# after upgrading from @angular 2.4.9 to @angular 4.0.0 @angular/cli shows invalid error

Tags: javascript, angular, web-deployment, angular-cli

After updating my packages from @angular 2.4.9 to @angular 4.0.0, `npm ls --depth 0` shows `@angular/compiler-cli@4.0.0 invalid` followed update guide from 
https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/

Well, everything seems running fine, still want to know about how to fix this and why is like so?

[image]

Comment: Delete the entire folder and run npm install again. You should do that from time to time even if you aren't updating major versions. `node_modules` can and will get corrupted eventually. `rm -rf node_modules` -> `npm install`.

Comment: have you upgraded typescript > 2.x

Comment: @PankajParkar why would that break it? Are you telling angular-cli v4.0.0 still doesn't work with TS 2.2.1?

Comment: used following cmd:  npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest typescript@latest --save

Comment: @AluanHaddad removed dir, and installed everything, now getting this error. Error: No module factory available for dependency type: ContextElementDependency

Comment: I've never heard of that injectable sorry, are you running locally or on some remote vm? npm install should be working.

Comment: Can i see your package.json file? what happens on npm start/ ng serve?

Answer (score 0):

Remove your node_modules folder and reinstall.

To solve the new error in your comments try this one: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46812648/1037613