# Angular No module factory available for dependency type: ContextElementDependency

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

Running `ng build` on my Angular 4 project give this error :

```
     14% building modules 40/46 modules 6 active ...es\@angular\http\@angular\http.es5.js
An error occured during the build:
Error: No module factory available for dependency type: ContextElementDependency
    at Compilation.addModuleDependencies (D:\dev\workspace\rep\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:213:21)
    at Compilation.processModuleDependencies (D:\dev\workspace\rep\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:202:8)
    at _this.buildModule.err (D:\dev\workspace\rep\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:350:14)
    at building.forEach.cb (D:\dev\workspace\rep\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:147:27)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at callback
```

I've read many Q/A on github & stackoverflow on this issue, but non of them helped me.

As the answers suggested i have removed webpack but this didn't help. Removed node_modules, removed webpack from package.json, run `npm install`, still didn't help. Cleaned cache of npm, removed webpack from package.json, run `npm install`, still no result. And many other similar suggestions didn't help.

When i remove webpack from package.json and run `npm install` i get following:

```
 Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/node/NodeTemplatePlugin' Error: Cannot
 find module 'webpack/lib/node/NodeTemplatePlugin'
     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
     at Object.<anonymous> (D:\dev\workspace\rep\node_modules\html-webpack-plugin\lib\compiler.js:11:26)
     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
     at Object.<anonymous> (D:\dev\workspace\rep\node_modules\html-webpack-plugin\index.js:7:21)
     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
```

When return webpack to package.json , run `npm install` and then run `npm list webpack` i get following result:

```
+-- @angular/cli@1.4.7
| `-- webpack@3.6.0
`-- webpack@3.8.1
```

Here is package.json of the project:

```
{
  "name": "somename",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "url": "",
  "copyright": "somec",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.5",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.5",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.5",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.5",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^4.4.5",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^1.21.0",
    "chart.js": "2.7.0",
    "core-js": "2.5.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "ng2-charts": "1.6.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "1.9.3",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rxjs": "5.4.3",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.4.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.6.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.13",
    "@types/node": "8.0.28",
    "codelyzer": "3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.6",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "ts-node": "3.3.0",
    "tslint": "5.7.0",
    "typescript": "2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.9.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  }
}
```

When i clone this repo on other machine , run `npm install` and then `ng build` it is okay, works alright, but on mine it gives this error. I've tried completely removing the repo from my machine, cloning from scratch and running `npm install` and `ng build`, still same error.

Can someone please tell what can be the reason of this behavior and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Steps I took to fix this problem in case if someone encounters it:

1. Package.json: remove webpack from DevDependencies
2. `rm -R node_modules` (remove node_modules folder)
3. `npm i -g webpack`
4. `npm i -g webpack-dev-server`
5. remove `package-lock.json` (if it's there)
6. `npm i`
7. `npm start`

I still don't completely understand the reasons why this happened.

Comment: Thank you! Most other fixes just involved removing node_modules then clearing cache and reinstalling. Looks like the global install of webpack did it for me.

Comment: For me, I now get `Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'`

Comment: the more i run in to this problem, the more i want to upvote this answer...

Comment: This error is stupid, but for long long time nobody fix it, the only way to solve it is to install webpack globally.

Comment: Also resolved when I deleted the `node_modules` and ran `yarn install`.

Comment: This worked for me, instead of rm -R node_modules, i used  rmdir /S /Q .\node_modules    to remove the node_modules directory on Windows.

Comment: my gitbash used to get hang after doing this steps ... i restarted my PC - which might have refreshed the cache and then finally it ran as required - thanks

Comment: This was helpful.  Something I found - **you absolutely have to go through all of these steps, in order, to clear the error up.** Even if a step in this seems unhelpful when you're reading through, _it's not!_  All these are necessary.

Answer (score 21):

Do `npm ls webpack`

If you see two versions of `webpack` (under @angular/cli and the root node_modules), Then that is the problem. Delete/Rename the webpack under `@angular/cli` and in the `.bin` folder of `@angular/cli`.

Problem solved for me

Comment: But in case if you update/reinstall @angular/cli you'll have this problem again because it will install webpack again

Comment: Thats why u should remove if from dev dependencies. This is so u don't remove packages just to reinstall them again

Comment: This was my issue. Removing from devDependencies and using my global version of webpack solved the problem.

Comment: @phacic thanks for this. I had to rename the two webpack references to get it working. But i still don't see webpack in my dev depedencies. How did it get installed that way and how do I make sure next update won't reinstall it back? Hope you are still around btw.

Comment: I just remove web pack from my package.json, remove the node_modules folder and do the process again and it worked for me. Thanks

Comment: As suggested its the problem of two versions of webpack. So need to uninstall the version under package.json. Issue link if anyone encounters this problem: https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/issues/581

Answer (score 2):

So i was having this issue and it took me forever to figure out. I kept trying to delete my node_modules directory then reinstall webpack. If i installed webpack locally or globally i would get the ContextElementDependency error. If i uninstalled webpack i would get webpack not found. Long story short the problem for me was my package-lock.json file. So i ran
"rm package-lock.json && rm -R node_modules"
and then i could successfully run "npm install" and "npm start".
Dont ask me why this works, but i hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thank you. package-lock.json was causing the issues for me

Answer (score 1):

1. [`npm dedupe`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-dedupe) - this will remove duplicate dependencies
2. `ng build`

Hope this will be helpful!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If there is many and different versions of webpack from "npm ls webpack" command this answer will do the trick